# When executing a Button in a message, how to get arguments of a SlashCommand that triggered this message?

Tags: c#, discord.net

Imagine a SlashCommand `/gallery san_francisco`, which responds with a simple Embed showing a random image tagged `san_francisco` from some web API, and a Button titled *"Another one!"*. The `san_francisco` part is a string parameter supplied by the user.

The button triggers a ComponentInteraction, which is supposed to replace the Embed with another random image tagged `san_francisco`.

Is it possible to get the original argument of the `/gallery san_francisco` command inside the ComponentInteraction handler?

Sample code:

```
public class GalleryModule : InteractionModuleBase<SocketInteractionContext>
{
    [SlashCommand("Gallery", "Start an image gallery of specified subject")]
    public async Task Gallery(string tag)
    {
        await RespondAsync(
            $"Pictures of {tag}:",
            embed: _galleryService.GetRandomImage(tag),
            components: new ComponentBuilder().WithButton("Another one!", "next-image").Build());
    }

    [ComponentInteraction("next-image")]
    public async Task ShowNextImage()
    {
        var interaction = ((SocketMessageComponent)Context.Interaction;
        var originalSlashInteraction = interaction.Message.Interaction;

        var galleryTag = originalSlashInteraction[...?];

        await interaction.UpdateAsync(mp =>
        {
            mp.Content = $"Another picture of {galleryTag}:";
            mp.Embed = _galleryService.GetRandomImage(galleryTag);
            mp.Components = new ComponentBuilder().WithButton("Another one!", "next-image").Build();
        });
    }
}
```

`originalSlashInteraction` is of type [`MessageInteraction<SocketUser>`](https://labs.discordnet.dev/api/Discord.MessageInteraction-1.html), which only has properties `Id`, `Type`, `Name` and `User`, but doesn't have a property for storing the arguments.

I considered storing the original `san_francisco` slash argument inside the Button's custom id (e.g. `next-image san_francisco`) and parsing it in the ComponentInteraction handler, but those can only be up to 100 characters long and wouldn't work for longer tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's available in the API. The best you can get is `Context.Interaction.Message.Interaction` which only gives you top level meta data (command's name, user, and type).

The easier thing to do would be use the interaction framework's wildcard parameters. Like you mentioned in your post this is limited to 100 characters, so if you exceed that limit you will need something to shorten it (maybe store the tag in a database and put the key value in the button's id)

```cs
    [ComponentInteraction("next-image:*")]
    public async Task ShowNextImage(string tag)
    { ... }
```